# How to correctly implement Use extension method on IAppBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The "Use" extension method on the IAppBuilder app has the following signature - `public static IApplicationBuilder Use(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task> middleware)`
It implies that it takes a Func delegate which accepts first argument as the context object , the second an asynchronous lambda expression and it returns a Task.
The official document states that Func should be a request delegate (next) and we await that in the current delegate call so that the other piece of middleware gets called.
I did something like this .

```
app.Use(async (context, temp) =>
{
    await temp();
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
});
```

where temp is

```
public Func<Task> temp = async () =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("In temporary task method");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
};
```

and practically does nothing than to sleep for 1 second. I am also not calling the next piece of middleware here which writes the response out.

I was expecting this code to crash but it sent out a response of Hello World.

Question - how did the next piece of middleware get invoked when it wasn't called explicitly in the temp delegate which I have passed in?
Usually we pass in next which is a request delegate assuming the next piece of middleware and do await next(); to explicitly call the next in chain.

I understand that I am missing something in the concepts of how these middlewares work in practice.

Comment: okay - so whats the question? whats the issue?

Comment: How did the next piece of middleware get invoked if I didn't explicitly call it ?

Comment: You _did_ explicitly call it. You just named it `temp` instead of `next`. The `temp` you `await` is not the same as the `temp` you create as a `Func<Task>`.

Comment: Thanks Kirk ! Yes I do realize that now. I also followed up on this by referring to an article written by Scott Allen. https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/09/17/how-the-next-delegate-works-in-asp-net-core-middleware.aspx. but I find this a bit strange , I could have a delegate method which could override "next" . It basically is just a pointer to a method so I wonder why the Func<Task> wasn't called.